# C# Deserialize List<T> Issue

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

This is the class I am trying to serialize and deserialize:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("RecipeStepWords")]
public class CRecipeStepsWords
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<RecipeStep> ReadRecipeSteps { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    public List<RecipeStep> WriteRecipeSteps { get; set; }

    public CRecipeStepsWords()
    {
        ReadRecipeSteps = new List<RecipeStep>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 8; x++)
        {
            ReadRecipeSteps.Add(new RecipeStep());
        }
        WriteRecipeSteps = new List<RecipeStep>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++)
        {
            WriteRecipeSteps.Add(new RecipeStep());
        }
    }

    public class RecipeStep
    {
        public String Test1 { get; set; }
        public String Test2 { get; set; }

        public RecipeStep()
        {
            Test1= "Sample 1";
            Test2 = "Sample 2";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, ReadRecipeSteps should have 8 items and WriteRecipeSteps should have 6.  However, whenever I run the program multiple times, the deserialized list gets added to,i.e., first run = ReadRecipeStesp.Count = 8, second run .Count = 16, etc.

Here is how I deserialize:

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, fName)))
{
    StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, fName));
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(RecipeStepsWords.GetType());

    RecipeStepsWords = (CRecipeStepsWords)x.Deserialize(objStreamReader);
    objStreamReader.Close();
}
```

I'm using VS 2010 for this. What I would like is to always have the correct number of items in the lists, 8 and 6, instead of having them added to every time it gets deserialized.  Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about .NET, but in Java, `ArrayList` uses an array as a backing store and switches the array out for a larger array as needed.  `List<T>` is the .NET equivalent of Java's `ArrayList<T>`.  The point being that the array is larger than the List's contents and is usually grown in powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc...).

Comment: Why are you adding `RecipeStep`s in the ctor (to any of the lists)? Looks like the deserializer adds the serialized elements to the existing collection (rather than replacing it, as it seems you expected).

Comment: Incidentally, you can see the size of a List<T>'s backing array by checking the `Capacity` property and shrink it to match `Count` by using the [`TrimExcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: @Powerlord All very correct, but irrelevant to the case. I doubt the serialization goes over the private array of the list class, or that it uses the `Capacity` instead of the `Count`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan By its very nature, serializing a `List<T>` would involve serializing the backing array as well.  Unfortunately, I've never looked at the code for List<T> to see exact what it does when serializing/deserializing to see how it sets the Capacity/Count when it unserializes.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan, I took out the add new RecipeStep() in the ctor, and that solved my initial problem. I put in some code to add to the lists up to the desired count after the file has been deserialized, and this seems to have resolved my issue.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Powerlord Of course the backing field array is *used*, but the point is that it isn't used *directly* from the outside, and my [correct] assumption was that the `List` class would serialize and deserialize properly regardless of the difference between the `Count` and `Capacity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an

[XmlArrayItem("ReadReceipe")] right after your xml array. Same for the WriteReciepe

So like this.

```
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem("ReadReceipe")]
    public List<RecipeStep> ReadRecipeSteps { get; set; }
```

I think what happens is you just keep adding those steps to the root, without having a parent node.

Let me know.

Comment: KonB, I tried this, and the same result is still happening.

Comment: Can you provide the XML you are getting? I would also name your XMLArray nodes as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Reset your object
RecipeStepsWords = new CRecipeStepsWords();
RecipeStepsWords = (CRecipeStepsWords)x.Deserialize(objStreamReader);
objStreamReader.Close();
```